# Missing output for LVM commands

Tags: lvm, sles

On a SLES12.2 machine, we can see:

```
SERVER:~ # lvs
SERVER:~ # vgs
SERVER:~ # pvs
SERVER:~ # echo $?
0
SERVER:~ #
```

that the usual LVM commands doesn't produce output. How could this be? Server booted up normally. Reboot sometimes helps, sometimes no (to get output for these basic commands).

Comment: Take a look at this - https://superuser.com/questions/421896/vgdisplay-and-lvdisplay-no-volume-groups-found

Comment: Please add result of `ps -ef | grep '[l]vmetad'` to your question (that's a lowercase "L" in square brackets, in case it's not clear).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `lvmetad` caching daemon was introduced recently and sometimes breaks LVM's implicit scanning.

```
pvscan --cache
```

should force LVM to rescan.

from: https://superuser.com/questions/421896/vgdisplay-and-lvdisplay-no-volume-groups-found

Comment: but anybody knows an official fix for this? years passed..

Comment: It wasn't introduced "recently". That might have been true in 2013, which is when [the answer you copied](https://superuser.com/a/665268/332907) was written.